# How to use for loop to print array in a page control (swift4)

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, uiviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

My code right now uses a `for` loop to print images placed in the assets folder. I want to do the same thing with text using a label. So in array `judo`. I would like each entry to be printed in order just like the way it is doing with thee images.

```
@IBOutlet var lz: UILabel!
var judo = ["a","b","c"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrol.delegate = self

    for image in 0...2 {
        lz.text = 

        let imageTo = UIImage(named: "\(image).png")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: imageTo)
        let xCord = view.frame.midX + view.frame.width * CGFloat(image)
        contenetWidth += view.frame.width
        scrol.addSubview(imageView)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for each loop to print all the elements in array `judo`.

```
for text in judo {
  print(text)// should print a,b,c
}

lz.text = judo[image]
```

Comment: I only want to print one element so on page control 1 I just want it to print out a. On Page control 2 I want it to print out b.

Comment: You did not mention anything about page control.... then what you can do is according to the pagecontrol index... print the element. .. something like.. I'll edit my answer.